# What's the easiest way to calculate the position of a square fixture in Box2D?

Tags: c++, box2d

I'm using the C++ Box2D library. I've created a body and have added multiple square fixtures to it. These square fixtures are offset from the body position (similar to what is done in the "multiple fixtures" section here: https://www.iforce2d.net/b2dtut/fixtures).

My idea is for a rendering system to iterate over the fixture and draw them to the screen. However, I can't seem to find a method for retrieving the X, Y and angle of the fixture. When stepping my Box2D world, the body X/Y/rotation position changes which changes the fixture's X/Y/rotation psoition.

Is there an easy way to extract this information from a square fixture? I could do the math myself to derive the position, however, it seems odd that Box2D wouldn't offer a solution to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Fixtures do not have any location or transform on their own.
2. Shapes have local points (e.g. `b2CircleShape` has a center, `b2PolygonShape` has a list of vertices). However, shapes can be reused in multiple fixtures/bodies. Therefore it makes no sense for them to know about any of the fixtures/bodies they are attached to.

To get a shape's location as it is attached to a body in world space, simply use the body's `GetWorldPoint` method:

```
body.GetWorldPoint(p);
```

where `p` is any local point of a shape attached to that body (e.g. the location of a `b2CircleShape` or a vertex of a `b2PolygonShape`).

Answer (score 0):

From wat you described, it sounds like you need a tool to calculate where everything is. I could be wrong on this but the closet thing I seen in the documentation for the product your using is "Ray Casting" and "AABB testing". Both are described in the [World Querying](https://www.iforce2d.net/b2dtut/world-querying) section of the documentation.